# Why Spark processing takes longer?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to learn Spark using Python (Pyspark).
I wrote this simple example:

```
from pyspark.shell import sc
import time

def Func(lines):
    lines = lines.lower()
    lines = lines.split()
    return lines

if __name__ == '__main__':


    full_name = "book_1.txt"
    N         = 10000

    start_time = time.time()
    with open(full_name) as myfile:
        head = [Func(next(myfile)) for x in range(N)]
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Regular processing: {end_time-start_time}")

    start_time = time.time()
    rdd      = sc.textFile(full_name, 2)
    rdd1     = rdd.map(Func)
    res      = rdd1.take(N)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Spark processing: {end_time - start_time}")
```

And it's seems that using spark takes loner:

```
Regular processing: 0.01978921890258789
Spark processing: 0.9811902046203613
```

1. I may have been wrong in understanding but one of the benefits of RDD being that parallel operation can be triggered is not it?
2. What do I need to update in the code in order to run it in parallel?
3. Also, if I run over my machine (8 cores), how many processes (or threads ?) will be generated ?

Answer (score 2):

Spark is not meant to be used for processing small datasets. It is built on top of Akka, which is an actor model implementation with quite heavy IPC. It takes a relatively long time for Spark to chop a job into tasks and to schedule their execution. Only when processing very large datasets, the communication and scheduling overhead gets amortised and you see the benefit of using Spark.

This is not Spark-specific. It is the case with virtually every other parallel processing paradigm, including MPI, OpenMP, CUDA, and so on.

Note that in your case there is even more PySpark-specific overhead. Since `Func` is not a JVM function (i.e., not written in Scala or Java), it cannot be executed in Spark itself. Instead, the content of the RDD is marshaled and sent to separate external Python processes (one per executor) where the Python function can be applied. Then the result is marshaled back into Spark.

Also, when performing simple operations on data read from files, you are mostly limited by the I/O speed and not by how many CPUs and threads you use to process the data. This is why large files are usually stored on distributed filesystems such as HDFS that provide much higher I/O bandwidth when many file blocks are read simultaneously from different nodes in the Hadoop cluster.